# Pentaho Data Integration JSON Output /" instead of "

Tags: java, json, escaping, etl, pentaho

Experiencing an issue with Pentaho JSON transformations. I imagine it is a simple issue I just don't know the tool. I have a JSON input and a JSON output, I am using the auto field mapping.

**INPUT:**

```
{
   "ArrayExample":[
      {
         "fruitId":"asdasg22389khsdall"
      }
   ],
   "name":"Test",
   "fruits":[
      "Apples",
      "Bananas"
   ]
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "ArrayExample":"[{\"fruitId\":\"asdasg22389khsdall\"}]",
         "fruits":"[\"Apples\",\"Bananas\"]",
         "name":"Test"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to just get "Apples" instead of \ "Apples \ " but I cannot seem to find the answers. I want to use the JSON in an API call, but the API call will not work with the \ ". I even tried using another API tool called Talend, which was having the same issue and even more.

Any help ***[greatly appreciated]***, at my wits' end.

configuration example   [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koPhk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated your transformation in my environment, and received the same result.
However, I have noticed the following:

1. Preview Data tab is showing the data with regular double quote, instead of escape-char double quote (").
2. When I try to continue the transformation, i.e. using JSON Output as an input for the next stage,
   it is aware of the escape-char double quote and transforms it into regular double quote.

Therefore, my conclusion is that you should either continue using the JSON in API call inside Pentaho, so it can process the escape-char double quote automatically,
or you should post-process the file as regular text file, in which you will manually transform each escape-char double quote into regular double quote.

Comment: Hi Rownum, Thank you for you answer! So in your testing you were able to for instance make a PUT call with a properly formatted JSON within pentaho? I went with Talend and a tSystem component calling python to do the transformations I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Text File Output**.

[Text File Output File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R3lM.png)

[Text File Output Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOWiq.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Oh nice, that is thinking outside the box. I am guessing I can do the same with Talend. Will have to try sometime. Thank you!